# Local timezone conversion for NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios7

I am trying convert NSDate into Local timeZone. I am doing like this

```
dateTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateTimeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d', 'yyyy', 'h':'mm a zzz"];
```

date looks like this `2013-10-05 11:00:00 +0000` . I am getting it as 04:30 PM which should be 04:30 AM. Anyway of making it work??

```
NSString *str = [dateTimeFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: Date formatters default to using the local timezone. No need to set it. And don't set both the style and a format. Do one or the other.

Comment: Show how you determine the output.

Comment: Don't forget that when you work with fixed format date formatters, you must set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: @rmaddy - It doesn't make any difference may i know what for this?

Comment: can you explain me to how to check whether the time is in 24 hr format or 12 hr format from NSDate.

Comment: NSDate it's only a time interval since a predetermined date (2001-1-1 GMT, I think), the 24/12 hour format is a matter of representation as a string. Also, what could possibly change in iOS 7 that makes your dates change to 12 hours of difference? Are you sure you set up your phone to the correct timezone?

Comment: No actually it returns same for all versions. I missed to notice. But i dont know how to check whether date is in 12 hr or 24hr format.

Comment: Yes my phones time zone is perfect. Yes i want to give correct string representation but instead of AM im getting PM.

Comment: @iUser: What is your time zone? And can you show the complete string `str` together with the corresponding `date`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
[dateTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd', 'yyyy', 'hh':'mm a zzz"];
```

Comment: This won't help. The only difference is how single digit days and hours would appear in the final string.

Comment: Yes it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot to this answer from Apple it should enlighten the topic: [About Date formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html)
 As maddy said you don't need to set time zone, the default one is picked from general settings in iOS to make the right conversion.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
formatter.dateFormat = @"MMM d', 'yyyy', 'h':'mm a zzz";
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```